# Rewrite everything to a single 'site down' page with Zeus Rewrite Rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, zeus

I'd like to make it so that any request for any file or page on my website gets directed to a single file: site_down.php

I know how to do this with apache rewrites but can't find a specific example for Zeus

Answer (score 0):

```
match URL into $ with ^
if matched then
    set URL = /site_down.php
endif
```